# Remove [''] from Python List

Tags: python

Hopefully a simple question. I have a Python list has left over special characters.

```
['', '\n', 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
```

I want to remove the `''` (two single quotes not a double quote) from the list (not always the first list value in the list). I am able to remove the `\n` by looping through the list and if the value matches `'\n'` then do `list.pop(i)`. However I can't find an equivalent way to search and remove for the `''`.

Comment: What's wrong with your approach for `\n` when you apply it to `''`? There should be absolutely no difference between the two

Comment: What is the difference between `'\n'` and `''`? I can't imagine a scenario where you have code that can remove one but not the other

Comment: Please include the code you used in order to solve the problem for `\n`. This will enable users to understand what your issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
l = ['', '\n', 'a', 'b', 'c']

l = [ x for x in l if x ]

print (l)
```

Output:

```
['\n', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and select explicitly elements not equal to an empty string:

```
lst = ['', '\n', 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
lst = [x for x in lst if x != ""]
```